# Simple Mysql select another row if field is empty

Tags: mysql

I have a multi-lingual table for the country like this:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
 country | lang | name
--------------------------------------------------------------------
 US      | en-US | United States
--------------------------------------------------------------------
 US      | fr    | États-Unis
--------------------------------------------------------------------
 US      | ar | الولايات المتحدة
--------------------------------------------------------------------
 US      | de |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to select the field "name" for the country 'US' for the lang 'de' but if the
name field is empty fallback to the language 'en-US'.

so will a query like this should be correct:

```
select name from countries where country='US' and name<>"" and lang in ('de', 'en-US')
```

I really need optimized query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to get the answer:

```
select name
from countries
where country = 'US' and name<>"" and lang in ('de', 'en-US')
order by lang = 'de' desc
limit 1;
```

If you have an index on `country, lang, name` then it should perform well.

EDIT:

This might perform better with the same index:

```
select coalesce((select name
                 from countries
                 where country = 'US' and name <> "" and lang = 'de'
                ),
                (select name
                 from countries
                 where country = 'US' and name <> "" and lang = 'en-US'
                )
               ) as name
```

EDIT II:

A standard SQL approach similar to the first is:

```
select (case when sum(case when lang = 'de' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
             then max(case when lang = 'de' then name end)
             else max(name)
        end) 
from countries
where country = 'US' and name <> "" and lang in ('de', 'en-US');
```

An aggregation on two rows should be quite fast in any database.  However, `the coalesce()` method should essentially just be two index lookups.

Comment: thanks Gordon for your answers, if I am looking for sql portability  not only mysql, what would be the first query, and for the second query does coalesce sql protable, I know my question titled for mysql only but since I am learning would be interested to know about portability. I know for mssql it uses the "top" instead of "limit".

Comment: @daliaessam . . . The second query is standard SQL and should work in most databases.  The first uses `limit`; different databases have different ways of implementing this functionality.